# How to launch multiple instance of an application in a single VSCode integrated terminal with split?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a compound launch configuration to launch two instance of an application like -

> ```
> "compounds": [
>     {
>       "name": "App 100/App 200",
>       "configurations": ["App 100", "App 200"]
>     }
> ]
> ```

This opens up IOL100 in one integrated terminal group and IOL200 in another integrated terminal group.
Is there a way to make them come in the same integrated terminal group? (with terminal split)

I want to achieve something like this.

[image: Expected behaviour]

Since usually we work with two instances of an Application and having them next to each other in a split terminal would give a better experience.
Any attribute inside compound launch is available to achieve this result?

Note - Related GitHub issues -

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/69619
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68123